# node-soap client: how to setup timeouts and keep-alive?

Tags: node.js, soap, keep-alive, connection-timeout, node-soap

Is there an easy way of setting up timeouts and keep-alive for [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) clients?

It would be useful to setup:

- socket connection timeout;
- socket read timeout;
- request timeout;
- keep-alive (enable/disable);
- keep-alive heartbeat interval.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to answer, but I was just setting up `node-soap` and got to this question.
So, to the point. You could create your own request object to override the request module. To do that you could just set the properties of the request object and then pass it in the options parameter when creating the soap client.

```
const request = require("request");
request.defaults({forever: true, ...});
```

You could have a look at the available properties from the request module [here](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback):